# Adding both panel.lmline and panel.smoothScatter to a lattice xyplot

Tags: r, lattice

I am trying to add a linear trend line to a scatterplot that has been smoothed by `panel.smoothScatter`.

Based on other posts, I tried adding `type=c("p","r")` but this does nothing. I also tried making the panel a function that calls both, but this results in a blank plot:

```
#plots smoothed scatter without trend line
p2 <- xyplot(y~x, grid=T, type=c("p","r"), panel=panel.smoothScatter)
#plots nothing
p2 <- xyplot(y~x, grid=T, type=c("p","r"), panel=function(...){panel.smoothScatter;panel.lmline})
```

How can I use multiple `panels` in one xyplot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to fix your custom panel function to actually call your desired panel functions properly

```
p2 <- xyplot(y~x, grid=T, panel=function(...){
    panel.smoothScatter(...)
    panel.lmline(...)
})
```

Comment: you're too fast for me!